# HTML editor — edit both start and end tag at once

Tags: html, editor

Is there an HTML editor which automatically changes the end tag when you edit the start tag?

Answer (score 2):

[Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/studio) Does.  Just set modify pair tag in Window Menu > Preferences > Aptana > Editor > HTML > Typing  It is off by default.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ has a bunch of [XML refactors](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/refactoring.html#XML-aware_dedicated_refactorings), one of which is rename tag.

Answer (score 0):

[e-texteditor](http://www.e-texteditor.com) can do this, though not as automatically as you probably want.  Ctrl+doubleclick on the beginning and ending tags, and change them that way.

Comment: It's probably done in a very similar manner, since e was built as a Windows version of TextMate.  Past that, no, I don't know :(

Comment: How to do this in dreamweaver?

Answer (score 0):

**IntelliJ IDEA 14.1** has this feature:

http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/files/2015/02/simultaneous_tag_editing_2.gif

For instance, if you want to change `div` to `span` in:

```
<div> Text </div>
```

it's enough to edit one of the tags and the other one will be changed in real time.