# Is there a Visual Studio shortcut for replacing the beginning and ending tag name in XAML/XML/HTML at once?

Tags: visual-studio, tags, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I want something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335799/html-editor-edit-both-start-and-end-tag-at-once) post but with Visual Studio.  This would be very helpful when editing XAML, XML, or HTML.

For instance:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button>I'm A Button</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

If I start changing the 'StackPanel' tag, I want to automatically change the end tag to match (say if I switch it to a 'Grid' instead).  I figure I could write a macro to do it, but I want to use a native approach first if available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeRush and Refactor pro from [devexpress](http://devexpress.com) will do this for you as well as a ton of other cool stuff.  It is a paid for product though I'm afraid - I am not aware of anything free that does this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you'll have to either:

1. Write a macro.
2. Write an add-on (or customize an existing open-source add-on).
3. Buy one of mentioned products (CodeRush or Refactor).